Error para agregar qcustomplot a mi proyecto qt con qmake

Buenas para todos, tengo este error al compilar mi proyecto de qt, en qmake, he descargado y agregado los archivos qcustomplot.h a Headers y qcustomplot.cpp a sources

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
